# Maven Dependency Project Not Found While Deploy to Glassfish 4

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a project IIFS-ejb (EJB project) and IIFS-common (jar file)

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>com.islandfurniture</groupId>
            <artifactId>IIFS-common</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I define the dependency as shown above

However, receive an error saying when i try to deploy the ejb project together with iifs-common to glassfish 4.0. The iifs-common project can be deployed while the ejb failed with the following error

```
 severe: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: iifs/common/exceptions/UserRoleNotFoundException
```

Please help thank you

Comment: After a while i realized I need to compile a jar file and to EJB will use methods from the jar file during runtime. How can i achieve it through maven?

Comment: remove the scope tag

Comment: I tried to remove the scope but it didn't work. The project was compiled into jar file under ear lib folder but the ejb jar file did not find it